# Difference between AWS Site-to-Site VPN and AWS VPC peering?

Tags: amazon-web-services

what is the difference between AWS Site-to-Site VPN and Inter-Region VPC Peering?

> You can establish peering relationships between VPCs across different AWS Regions (also called Inter-Region VPC Peering). This allows VPC resources including EC2 instances, Amazon RDS databases and Lambda functions that run in different AWS Regions to communicate with each other using private IP addresses, without requiring gateways, VPN connections, or separate network appliances.

Comment: One connects your on premise system to a VPC, the other connects different VPCs together.

Comment: Maybe this is a good training. It is free. https://www.aws.training/Details/eLearning?id=72711

Answer (score 5):

AWS Site-to-Site enables access to your remote network from your VPC. In other words, an AWS Site-to-Site VPN connection connects your VPC to your datacenter.

A VPC peering connection is a networking connection between two VPCs that enables you to route traffic between them using private IPv4 addresses or IPv6 addresses. Using VPC peering, you can connect your own VPCs, VPCs in different accounts, and even VPCs across different accounts.

Please refer to VPC FAQs [here](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant, "...even VPCs across different regions."